# Security for user-uploaded images

Tags: javascript, express, vue.js

Currently coding an API call where users can upload an avatar image.

The stack I'm working with is basically node.js / Vue.js  (front end) and node.js / Express (back end) on top of Linux.

I can create an API and front end for this process, but I'm worried about security.  My approach currently is to store them on the same (back-end) server where the DB will reside.  DB is Mongo.

Seeing as how the image sizes are probably comparably small and the number of images should be one-to-one with the number of users, could I get away with placing the images in a Mongo DB collection, or should I go with the filesystem?

And **if I go with the filesystem, what are the security implications?**

NOTE: I've perused a lot of posts with similar questions prior to creating this post, but most are for different technology stacks or combinations.  However, if you feel I missed something, feel free to share it.

Comment: I've personally worked on systems that store large numbers of pdfs in mongo.  It's not a problem, so long as mongo is given enough memory.

Comment: However asking about security implication is pretty unclear what you are concerned about.

Comment: don't store the filenames based on what the upload filename is, that's a recipe for disaster (imagine the filename being `../../../../../../etc/passwd\x00.jpg` or something to that effect), it's faster to load the images from filesystem rather than db, it's easier to implement "Range" and stuff like that if it's from the filesystem rather than a db, if you store it in db you will almost certainly load the entire image in ram before sending, but if you load it from a filesystem you can just send it in chunks,

Comment: Thank you for the note Taptar; any comment on performance of doing it this way?  I really like the idea of storing them in a DB as the 'security' is then just as good as the DB security.

Comment: @Taplar let me guess, you load the entire file in ram before starting to send the file, right? you fetch the entire file from the db first, storing it all in ram, and when you got the entire file from the db inserted to ram, you start sending it to the client?

Comment: The files are converted to a `byte[]` to be stored in mongo.  And each record is associated to the person who owns it by the normal ObjectId associations.  When we need to serve it back to the user, we specifically pull the record from the different collection by it's id, and then return it to the client.  We only pull the data out of mongo if it is specifically required.  Whenever all we need is the name of the file, we perform a mongo search that excludes the `byte[]` data for performance reasons, as we don't need it in that case.

Comment: @Taplar right, but when a client do request the entire file: if it's a 1 GB file, you will use 1GB of ram while transferring the file, right? and if 10 people download that 1GB file simultaneously, your code will use 10GB of ram while transferring the file, right? each transfer has their own copy of the file in ram while sending it to the client?

Comment: I would have to check, but I believe there is a filesize limit we enforce.  But regardless of that, if the server and/or mongo decides to put that in ram or off load it to disk while it does its work, is not something I'm intimately aware of. @hanshenrik

Comment: @hanshenrik It looks like there's an option called gridfs-stream that can handle collection storage without having to load the entire file in RAM.  I'm researching it now, but its looking promising:  https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/gridfs/